# list of custom functions that might be called

Tags: javascript, html, function, call

is there a way to get all custom functions names that will/may be called to an array? Example:

```
<button onclick="foo()">lol</button>
<script>function foo(){
    alert("clicked");
}
function boo(){
    alert("clicked");
}
</script>
```

Should return `foo` in the array, not `boo`
Here the function foo might not be called but I still want to have a list (array?) of all of the custom functions that are in code (not necessarily called). Just to clarify: I want to know if the function **might** be called not if it exists and don't need to know if it **will** be executed either. How can I do this efficiently?

Edit: I want this as a replacement to the explicit declaration I previously used:

```
using blah;
```

and the only thing the new implicit declarations should do is, find function names, compare them to the list of functions (array) and write matches to another array

Comment: That might be called from the general code, or only from event handlers?

Comment: @Scimonster general code including external files

Comment: That'll be very hard.

Comment: @Scimonster ouch, I have _got_ to do this in order to make my lib work

Comment: It sounds like you might be suffering from [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). How about you clarify why you need this?

Comment: @Scimonster maybe, but I **highly** doubt that.. I need my lib to get a list of functions that will be called so that it can load them using AJAX range requests

Comment: Given some JS source code, you can use a parser such as esprima and traverse the AST to find function calls. But I don't understand yet why you want to do this so that might not be a viable solution.

Comment: Question unclear. Do you want to know all functions of a given object? Or all functions of object AND functions called by these functions recursively? In your example, `foo` is not a member of your button.

Comment: @FelixKling take Jquery as an example. either you download a version that only has the features you want (still all aren't used) or you download the whole library everytime you want to use it. I want my library to load only the functions the specific page uses which I have accomplished using AJAX and range requests but the user must declare the functions explicitly before using them (`using blah;`). I want this to happen automatically

Comment: I don't think it's even *possible* in a general sense. For degenerative cases such as `obj[new Date().valueOf()]()`, you will not be able to know what functions on `obj` will be called, because it's not computable.

Comment: @user3088260: This is impossible. Consider: `if(Math.random() > 0.5) { foo(); }`. How would your script determine if `foo` will ever run? Or: `var s = "notfoo"; val[s.slice(3)]()`, which is equivalent to `val.foo()`. How would your script work in this case?

Comment: @univerio What if I have a list of functions that might be used?

Comment: @Jordan I don't _care_ if it's called or no. I just want to know if it might be called like this `if(1 === 2)foo()` will still return the function

Comment: You can't do it while the client code runs because the functions have to exist beforehand. You can't do it statically (reliably) because you can't access the source of scripts loaded via a URL. If you have a single root object (like jQuery), you can use proxies once they are supported by browsers: http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:direct_proxies

Comment: @user3088260 Same thing. Due to the the dynamic nature of JS, how would you know, at runtime, what the possible values of `new Date().valueOf()` is going to be, even if you had a list of possible functions? You might be able to do it for simple cases, but you have to be prepared for false negatives (functions that you think won't be called but actually will be). It sounds like false negatives are not acceptable in your use case, so this whole endeavor is simple impossible.

Comment: @univerio I don't mind loading 500 bytes more than required. As I only want an exact replacement of my using thing that does the function fishing itself

Comment: @user3088260 You misunderstand. Having false negatives means your code will be incorrect. It is literally not possible to prevent false negatives in this setup **unless you load all functions**; this is not simply an issue of loading 500 extra bytes. The other thing you could do, if you control all code, is to not write any degenerate cases. e.g. you can enforce that all function calls be of the form `obj.foo()`, in which case you can use the AST parsing solution.

Comment: @univerio I meant if it misses a few functions it doesn't matter

Comment: @user3088260 Then in that case you can use the AST parsing solution.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, it's impossible to know until it actually is called. There are so many different ways a function could be called. For example, these will all call `foo()`:

```
foo();
window.foo();
this.foo();
window['foo']();
eval('foo()');
eval('foo')();
window['f'+'o'+'o']();
// and so on
```

The only thing that might possibly work is to get all of the functions from the `window` object, and then do a regex search for calling them. The obvious caveat is that it won't catch most of my examples above.

Comment: how about basic `foo()` calls?

Comment: Those you might be able to find with a regex, as i said.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get any calls from `onclick` attributes (rather than just find functions that are defined in your JavaScript) you can use:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('*');
var clickAttributeCode = [];

for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    if (elems[i].onclick) {
        clickAttributeCode.push(elems[i].getAttribute('onclick'));
        console.log(elems[i].getAttribute('onclick'));
    }
}
```

This won't get dynamically appended events, only the events actually placed in the  `onclick=""` html attribute. This is important as this is not the recommended way of binding events. To illustrate, the following would not be found:

```
function go() {
    
}

document.getElementById('blah').onclick = go;
```

## Added Note

Assuming you want to do a "load on demand", you could *almost* do this by detecting the missing function and then loading it, for example using `window.onerror` and parsing the error to find the missing function name. The problem is the message differs by browser so this would be a very flaky system. Here are just two of the error messages you can get from calling `doIt()` when the function isn't defined.

> 'doIt' is undefined
>
> ReferenceError: doIt is not defined

However... there is a better way. If you want module loading (which seems to be what you are alluding to with your comments) you can use [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) to load parts of your program on demand in a browser. It is a very mature method of doing so.

Comment: Example of the workings and failings of this method... http://jsfiddle.net/kg22ndck/

Comment: The click thing was just an example. I need all functions

Comment: You need a tool for that - some IDEs like Visual Studio and WebStorm can "find all references" to a function (although this is done using static analysis and may not be 100% accurate if you have funky code). You could become an expert on the TypeScript compiler - when it compiles code it creates a code tree, which might give you half an answer (it will only tell you what references there are in code, and won't include calls from HTML pages or inline JavaScript). Essentially, what you are requesting is a very big ask - you would need to write something the size of a web browser to do this.

Comment: I'm making a lib and can't check everyone's code. That's why the JavaScript has to do it